# How to get instance of test class in xUnit

Tags: c#, xunit

Here is my test class

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class TestClass : TestBase
    {
        public TestClass(ITestOutputHelper output, TestScenario tScenario): base(output, tScenario)
        {
        }

        [Theory]
        [MyCustAttrib("data")]
        [MemberData(nameof(GetTestData))]
        public void Test_Method(string arg1, string arg2)
        {
            //Assign 
            //Act
            //Assert
        }
    }

    public abstract class TestBase : XunitContextBase, IClassFixture<TestScenario>
    {
        public TestScenario testScenario = null;
        public TestBase(ITestOutputHelper output, TestScenario tScenario) : base(output)
        {
             testScenario = tScenario;
        }
    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple =false, Inherited =true)]
    public class MyCustAttrib : BeforeAfterTestAttribute
    {
        private string id;

        public MyCustAttrib(string id)
        {
            id = id;
        }

        public override void Before(MethodInfo methodUnderTest)
        {
            base.Before(methodUnderTest);
            //TO-DO
            //Access testScenario field of the runtime instance of TestClass.
        }
    }
}
```

How do I get the instance of Testclass in "Before" override method of MyCustAttrib?
Goal here is to pass test data between different iterations of Test_Method using testScenario field of TestClass.